# Cypress in Docker can't connect to angular localhost on port 4200

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, cypress

In Jenkins I am running the frontend angular service in Docker and want also run Cypress and connect to the running angular server.

In Angular Dockerfile is EXPOSE 8080, what I can't change, but the Cypress BaseURl is set to : http://localhost:4200.

That's why I am mapping that port, when building the frontend:

```
sh 'docker build -t myimage3 .'
sh 'docker create --name frontend --network my-net -p 4200:8080 myimage3'
sh 'docker start frontend'
```

The frontend is up and running in container.

Cypress I am running on the same network:

```
sh 'docker build -t myimage4 .'
sh 'docker create --name test --network my-net myimage4'
sh 'docker start testrepo'
```

But for some reason cypress can't connect to localhost on 4200 port:

```
Cypress could not verify that this server is running:

  > http://localhost:4200

We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your `baseUrl`.

Cypress automatically waits until your server is accessible before running tests.

We will try connecting to it 3 more times...
We will try connecting to it 2 more times...
We will try connecting to it 1 more time...

Cypress failed to verify that your server is running.
```

The cypress Dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM cypress/base

WORKDIR /test

COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY ./cypress.json .

RUN npm run test
```

I tried to put `EXPOSE 4200` before the last line there, with no luck.

Seems it can't connect to localhost:4200 from another container, even if the network is the same.
Unfortunately I can't change the baseURL for Cypress, because I need it as localhost:4200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are on the same network then `frontend:8080` should work for you.

Or `host.docker.internal:4200`, as localhost shouldn't be used within a docker container.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/

Comment: The problem is in cypress.json I can't change the baseURL, because I am using cypress also on my local machine and there I need "baseUrl": "localhost:4200".

Comment: In that case you can try this workaround: create alternative cypress_ci.json file to be used by CI, with different baseUrl that works for jenkins. Then in Dockerifle switch to another script: npm run ci, and in this script while running cypress specify another config file with this flag: --config-file cypress_ci.json.
Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#cypress-json

Answer (score 1):

localhost (your front end angular) is not accessible from the cypress docker image.

try replacing `localhost` with the name of the docker image you want to connect to. in your case `myimage3`.